# How can I add elements to an NSDictionary in the following format?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, nsdictionary

I have an `NSArray` of names and ages. Now I am trying to create a new `NSDictionary` with item 0 holding the first name and first age and item 1 holding the second name and second age from the corresponding `NSArray`? Is that possible?

In my `viewDidLoad`:

```
NSMutableArray *Names = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSMutableArray *ages = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    [Names addObject:[candidates objectAtIndex:i]];
    [ages addObject:[studenAge objectAtIndex:i]];
}
```

But how can I make an `NSDictionary` from this by order?

**Final result**

I want to write this `NSDictionary` into a .plist so it look like this:

`Details
{
item 0
{
name:rahul
age:25
}
item 1
{
name:ram
age:26
}
item 2
{
name:aajy
age:20
}
item 4
{
name:raj
age:25
}
}`

Comment: Since your question is not very clear, why don't you show us the structure you would like to end up with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dictionaries do not have an order.

Probably you want to add dictionaries to the array:

```
NSMutableArray *persons=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];    
for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
{
  [persons addObject:@ { @"name" : candidate[i], @"age" : studenAge[i] }];
}
```

You can sort this array with the sort-Methods of NSArray, NSMutableArray.

Comment: What should be possible or not!?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @Amin, dictionaries don't maintain order and since you seem to want an indexed access here is what I suggest as the final structure: an array of dictionaries:

```
NSMutableArray *details = [NSMutableArray array];
for (int i=0;  i<4;  i++) {
    [details addObject:@{@"name": canditate[i], @"age":studentAge[i]}];
}
```

This will give you the following structure:

```
[{name:rahul, age:25}, {name:ram age:26},...]
```